# CSS Style in webgrid MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

**I want to apply CSS style in following code but i couldnt find the way. I want to add style to image as width 50px and height 50px**

```
grid.Column(format:(item) =>
    {
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/BrandImages/" + item.BrandImage)))
            {
                return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", @Url.Content("~/Content/BrandImages/" + item.BrandImage)));
            }
            else
            {
                return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/BrandImages/noimage.jpg")));
            }
        }
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple solutions

1-You can add inline width and height properties to your img element

```
  return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img style=\"width:50px; height:50px;\" src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", @Url.Content("~/Content/BrandImages/" + item.BrandImage)));
```

2- In your global stylesheet you can define new style like below

```
.myImageClass{
    width:50;
    height:50px;
}
```

then you can add this class your image elements

```
return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img class=\"myImageClass\" src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/BrandImages/noimage.jpg")));
```